# Python / Requests, download file from .aspx website after logging in

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Python/requests.

I need to:

1. log in a website
2. change a parameter
3. download a file according to change in 2)

Attached the images with form/payload after download completion (Please feel free to ask me more, if you don't find me enough descriptive).

[image: DownloadDiagram.aspx]
[image: DownloadDiagram_1of3]
[image: DownloadDiagram_2of3]
[image: DownloadDiagram_3of3]

My idea was:

```
url = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/Start.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f'
protectedurl = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/FixedPages/Dashboard.aspx'
downloadurl = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/Redirect/DownloadDiagram'

# your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
  'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtUserName': user,
  'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtPassword': pw
}

# ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print(p.status_code, p.headers)

    # authorised request
    r = s.get(protectedurl)
    print(r.status_code, r.headers)
    
    # download request
    d = s.get(downloadurl)
    print(d.status_code, d.headers)
```

I get for all 200 status code, but download doesn't start.

Here you can find the POST payload after logging in:

[image: AfterLoggingIn_1of2]
[image: AfterLoggingIn_2of2]

Thanks, Please please please help me!

I would like to have more clear:

1. should I add headers to post/get requests? Which headers?
2. Should I add more to the payload? What exactly?
3. Should I use straight just 1-2 url(s)? Which one/which ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to do here but it should be possible. This is an ASP site so you need to get the __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR for every page you navigate from and include it in the payload. I would include everything in the payload, even the blanks stuff as well as replicate the headers. See the code below for how to login.

Then once you login you can replicate the network call to change the date, again you need to process the __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR from the page you are moving from and include it in the payload. (use a function like below and just call it with each move).

When you expand the image you will see another network call which you need to replicate, the response will have HTML you can parse and you can find the image in this tag:

```
<img id="UserControlShowEnergyAndPower1$_diagram" src="/chartfx70/temp/CFV0113_101418049AC.png"
```

If it's not that exact chart you want then right click the chart and copy-image-address then look for that image url in the HTML to see where it is.

then you can do something like this to save the file:

```
img_suffix = soup.find('img',{'id':'UserControlShowEnergyAndPower1$_diagram'})['src']
image_name = img_suffix.split('/')[-1]

image_url = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/'+img_suffix
 
image_data = s.get(pdf_url) # where s is the requests.Session() variable 

print(f'Saving image')
with open(image_name,'wb') as file:
    file.write(image_data.content)
```

Below is how I logged in but you can take it from here to navigate to your image:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_views(resp):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,'html.parser')
    viewstate = soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
    viewstate_gen = soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})['value']

    return (viewstate,viewstate_gen)

s = requests.Session()

user = 'your_email'
pw = 'your_password'

headers =   {
    'accept':'*/*',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    }

url = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/Start.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f'
protectedurl = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/FixedPages/Dashboard.aspx'
downloadurl = 'https://www.sunnyportal.com/Redirect/DownloadDiagram'

landing_page = s.get(url,headers=headers)

print(landing_page)

viewstate,viewstate_gen = get_views(landing_page.text)

# your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
    '__EVENTTARGET':'',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
    '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':viewstate_gen,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtUserName':user,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtPassword':pw,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$LoginBtn':'Login',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$RedirectURL':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$RedirectPlant':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$RedirectPage':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$RedirectDevice':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$RedirectOther':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$PlantIdentifier':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$ServiceAccess':'true',
    'ClientScreenWidth':'1920',
    'ClientScreenHeight':'1080',
    'ClientScreenAvailWidth':'1920',
    'ClientScreenAvailHeight':'1050',
    'ClientWindowInnerWidth':'1920',
    'ClientWindowInnerHeight':'979',
    'ClientBrowserVersion':'56',
    'ClientAppVersion':'5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',
    'ClientAppName':'Netscape',
    'ClientLanguage':'en-ZA',
    'ClientPlatform':'Win32',
    'ClientUserAgent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hiddenLanguage':'en-gb'
    }

new_headers =   {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-ZA,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,de;q=0.6',
    'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length':'3917',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'DNT':'1',
    'Host':'www.sunnyportal.com',
    'Origin':'https://www.sunnyportal.com',
    'Pragma':'no-cache',
    'Referer':'https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/Start.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f',
    'sec-ch-ua':'" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile':'?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform':'"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
    }

login = s.post(url,headers=new_headers,data=payload)

print(login)
print(login.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Login works! But I am having hard time with the rest

Comment: I need to download the csv file, not an image

Comment: actually nothing works, because there is a problem with cookies. Every header need cookie and need to catch the cookie net of our browser manual reload.